# Mysql Big Table Optimization

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, indexing

We have a 10-year-old website that has been using SMF. Now we wrote our very own forum script but since we are unexperienced developers, we have no idea about optimizing. Our messages table is too big (about 2 gigabytes including indexes, 2.654.193 rows total). SMF was using this table really fast but our new forum script causes high system load average.

Here is the query list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Mpr.jpg

Here is the table structure and indexes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kDy9.jpg

Note: We use APC for acceleration and Memcached for caching. I'm a hundred percent sure that the messages table (and topics table maybe) is slowing our website.

Comment: use less IN()'s more joins. more index's on sortable columns

Comment: Try xdebug profiler to see what is slowing down from PHP side. Also debug for slow queries at MySQL slow queries log to see what's slowing down from MySQL side, profile them and think about using correct indexing. Also try to avoid count(*) - instead use count(id)

Comment: @sanis `SELECT * FROM topics as t1 LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, topic_id as tid, poster, body, post_date, poster_ip, subject FROM messages as t9 ORDER BY post_date DESC) as t2 ON t1.topic_id = t2.tid WHERE (super_pinned = 0 AND pinned = 0) AND (room_id = 45 OR (mirror_id = 45 AND room_id IN (45))) GROUP BY t1.topic_id` This query takes forever. How can I optimize it?

Comment: Remove subselect and move it to separate query if that's possible. Subselects are super slow. I'm not really deep into database structure to say exactly what to do with this query. All I can say, try to avoid subselects.

Answer (score 2):

This is just the right moment to learn all about SQL indexing.

[Proper indexing is *THE* way to improve SQL performance](http://www.slideshare.net/MarkusWinand/indexes-neglectedperformanceallrounder/7). [Indexing has to be done by developers](http://www.slideshare.net/MarkusWinand/indexes-neglectedperformanceallrounder/22).

Consider starting here (it's the free web-edition of my book [SQL Performance Explained](http://sql-performance-explained.com/)

- http://use-the-index-luke.com/

Major disclaimer: all links go to my own content.

Comment: Even though I solved the problem by editing the query, I will read your content as soon as possible. Thank you.